# Displaying PDF files in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I am new to react and I'm trying to display a PDF from a selectable list of links of my PDFs stored inside the src directory. For PDF viewing I used the code from here: https://npm.io/package/react-pdf

[Image of my display page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZkLz.png)

So I have a small table at the half left side of the screen and if I select one of the links it should open the pdf at the right side of the screen.
What I only managed was to put the `<ViewPdf/>` function with an already hardcoded pdf file that's how I displayed it at the right side.

**My question is how can I implement such a case where I can click a link from the table and it displays the file at the right side.**
Here is my code:

```
import ViewPdf from '../../../components/ViewPdf'
import {Table,Col,Row,Button} from 'reactstrap'

const DocTable = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Documents</span><br/>
    <Table bordered hover size="sm">
      <thead>
        <br/>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Document Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1-86</th>
          <td><Button color="link">Medical Insurance Claim</Button></td>
          <td>Signed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">0-34</th>
          <td><Button color="link">Household Insurance</Button></td>
          <td>Signed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2-24</th>
          <td><Button color="link">Car Insurance</Button></td>
          <td>Not Signed</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
    <br/>
    </>
  );
}

const DocumentList=()=>{

    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
        <Col xs="6">
          {DocTable()}
        </Col>

        <Col xs="6">
       <ViewPdf/>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      </div>
    );
  
}
export default DocumentList
```

Comment: Do you need to implement a button in the "DocumentList" component or in "DocTable"?

Comment: I assumed that you need the button on the left side in the "DocTable" component and have posted my answer. please give me the feedback about the result, thanks.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much let me try it and give feedback

Comment: Tried it and its working exactly as I needed. Thank you for your assistance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a button with a handler function to toggle between `hide/show` situations. also, a state variable is needed to store the current situation:

```
const DocTable = ({isVisible, onToggle}) => {
  return (
    <>
     // ... rest of the codes

     <button onClick={onToggle}>
       {isVisible? "Hide" : "Show"}
     </button>

     // ... rest of the codes
    </>
  );
}
```

Now essential parts added to the `DocTable` component, back to the `DocumentList` component and implement the state and the handler:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const DocumentList= () => {
   const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false) // false to hide the PDF for the first time

   const handleToggle = () => {
     setIsVisible(prevState => !prevState)
   }
   
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
        <Col xs="6">
          <DocTable isVisible={isVisible} onToggle={handleToggle}/>
        </Col>

        <Col xs="6">
          { isVisible && <ViewPdf/> }
        </Col>
      </Row>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Now, with click the button on the `DocTable` component, `handleToggle` function will invoke and change the `isVisible` value, at the end the `isVisible` variable determine to show `ViewPdf` component or not.